# Why can't a non-coordinate basis be expressed as derivatives with respect to any coordinates?

Tags: differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, vector-fields

In Schutz, Geometrical Methods of Mathematical Physics book, pg 44, vector fields on a manifold with coordinates $x^i$ are defined as
$$V=\frac{d}{d\lambda}=V^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$$
$$W=\frac{d}{d\phi}=W^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$$

It was said that if ${d}/{d\lambda}$ and $d/d\phi$ are two elements of a basis, then they will not be expressible as derivatives with respect to any coordinates. Such a basis is a non coordinate basis.

What does author mean in the above sentence? Does he mean $$\frac{d}{d\lambda} \neq V^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$$ $$\frac{d}{d\phi} \neq W^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}~?$$
If yes, doesn't it contradict the fact vector fields can be expressed in the form of the first two equations?

Comment: You can compare it with the example of differentials in thermodynamics, if you are familiar with that. Or notice that if a vector field has a non-zero curl then it cannot be the gradient of any scalar field. These are related ideas.

Answer (score 2):

A set of $n$ vector fields do not generally constitute a coordinate basis of an n-dimensional manifold, because you cannot take them all simultaneously to,
$$
V=\frac{d}{d\lambda}=V^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}=\frac{\partial}{\partial u^1}
$$
$$
W=\frac{d}{d\phi}=W^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}=\frac{\partial}{\partial u^2}
$$
etc. Where these $u^i$ are these alleged coordinates in which the basis looks like a bunch of pure partial derivatives.
The reason is that, in general,
$$
\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial u^{i}},\frac{\partial}{\partial u^{j}}\right]=0
$$
Now, in general too, the commutators of $n$ vector fields do not vanish.
I hope that was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Any basis at a *point* can be expressed by a coordinate system, but this can't be done over a *neighbourhood* of a point. There are integrability constraints. These constraints are encapsulated in  the Frobenius theorem which says that the Lie brackets of vector fields that constitute the frame field must vanish.

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct sentence should be:
"If / and / are two elements of a basis, then they will not be expressible ***in general*** as derivatives with respect to any coordinates."
And then, this would be a non-coordinate basis.

Maybe the author avoided the double "in general" as it is just before used.